# Setting absolute screen position of Bokeh Charts in Web App

Tags: python, web-applications, bokeh

I am trying to set the absolute position of a Bokeh Chart inside a Layout so that one of the plots is shown on top of another plot. Right now when I am plotting something like this:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc 
from bokeh.plotting import figure 
from bokeh.layouts import layout 
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(1,10.1,0.1) 
y = [i**2 for i in x]

categories = ['A', 'B'] 
values = [1000, 1500]

fig1 = figure(width=600,plot_height=600, title="First Plot")
fig1.line(x=x, y=y)

fig2 = figure(width=200,plot_height=250,x_range=categories,
title="Second Plot") fig2.vbar(x=categories, top=values, width=0.2)

l = layout([[fig1,fig2]]) 
curdoc().add_root(l)
```

The result will be this:

[image: Bokeh Layout with Line an Bar Cart next to each other]

What I am searching for is some way to make it look like that:

[image: Bokeh Layout with Bar Chart inside Line Chart]

How can this result be achieved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with (works for Bokeh v1.0.4). You need to move your mouse over the plot to get the other one jump inside but you could also copy the JS code from the callback and manually add it to the HTML generated by Bokeh so you achieve the same result.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.layouts import Row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, BooleanFilter, CustomJS, BoxSelectTool, HoverTool
import pandas as pd

plot = figure(tools = 'hover', tooltips = [("x", "@x"), ("y", "@y")])
circles = plot.circle('x', 'y', size = 20, source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y':[1, 2, 3]}))

inner_plot = figure(name = 'inner_plot', plot_width = 200, plot_height = 200)
lines = inner_plot.line('x', 'y', source = ColumnDataSource({'x': [8, 9, 10], 'y':[8, 6, 8]}))

code = """  div = document.getElementsByClassName('bk-root')[0];            
            tooltip_plot = div.children[0].children[1]
            tooltip_plot.style = "position:absolute; left: 340px; top: 350px;"; """

callback = CustomJS(code = code)
plot.js_on_event('mousemove', callback)

show(Row(plot, inner_plot))
```

Result:

[image]